# how to find pair of any two letters that appears at least twice in the string without overlapping

Tags: java, ruby, regex

How can i find pair of any two letters that appears at least twice in the string without overlapping?

For example, in the string '`adjkoedjeoieadkkji`' i should find `ad` because it happens twice.

In the string '`adjkobbbeoieadkkji`' i should NOT find `bb` because the two occurrences overlap.

I've tried with `/^([a-z]{2}).*(\1)$/` it matches only '`abab`'
still trying from my side please help me someone experts in regex

Comment: @randy i'have edited the question

Comment: check **[this](https://regex101.com/r/yU1nG4/1)**

Comment: you need to remove the anchors or use `^([a-z]{2}).*(\1).*$`

Comment: @rock321987 thanks , please add your answer below then i can reward :)

Comment: updated the answer a bit..because two continuous alphabets can be anywhere..I presume..have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string does not necessarily end after finding `\1`. So you are getting nothing. You can use

```
^.*?([a-z]{2}).*?(\1).*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yU1nG4/3)**

Comment: How this is used to get from string `adjkobbbeoieadkkji` as result `ad`?

Comment: @SubOptimal can you elaborate?

Comment: @SubOptimal are you talking about finding all repeated characters?

Comment: Yes. I cannot see how this should work with a `Pattern.compile(..)` to get the expected result.

Comment: @SubOptimal the question says to find a match if its there in the string..you can access the first capturing group for the match

Comment: Ok. Got it. The OP was not asking for to find also multiple pairs in the string (e.g. in `adjkoedjeoieadddkkjioe` -> `ad` and `oe`). I was misleaded by the solution from Diyarbakir. As his one would do it.

Comment: @SubOptimal that would be difficult(_nearly impossible_) to do with regex alone

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
public static final Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile("((\\w\\w))(?=.*\\1)");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "adjkoedjeoieadddkkji";
    Matcher m = REGEX.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.err.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Only prints:

`ad`

Overlapping `ddd` is not matched.